# Git clone issue; fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git

So I have a weird issue. 
I'm hosting a project over at a Git repository, I have a local box (mac os x) and a remote production box (Linux).

Cloning the Git repository (which is being hosted by codebasehq) from my local machine works great, no issues. Cloning it from my remote box makes it fail with the index-pack failed err.

It worked in the beginning but as the project has grown the issues has become more and more frequent and I now have to revert to getting a tar archive of my repository seeing as a git clone now always fails on the remote machine while still always succeeding on my local machine.

All the pack utilities are in the path, I have run Git gc multiple times and pushed, still the same issue. Any ideas?

**Edit**

So I'm accessing the repos by ssh and there is no other error message than the paste underneath. :( Still have the same issue, really annoying.

```
Receiving objects: 100% (9830/9830), 51.14 MiB | 1940 KiB/s, done.
fatal: index-pack failed1/2570)
```

Comment: At what stage does the error happen (strace may help answer that)? Could it be a flaky network?

Comment: Post the full error message ?
Enough free space on disk?  Cloning locally would reuse pack file - it take lessor space.

Comment: How are you connecting to the remote? `index-pack` is used to create an index from a pack that already exists; the primary ways I could see it failing are if the pack is corrupted or if there's insufficient memory to read in the whole pack. Is there really no specific error?

Comment: Updated the post with the full error message and a better descr

Comment: try running `git clone` like this:
GIT_TRACE=/tmp/clone.log git clone server:/repo.git
And take a look at the clone.log. Anything interesting in it?